# Using EWS Managed API version 2.2 how do I find delegators

Tags: api, exchange-server, managed

We have a calendar app using EWS Managed API.  We want to gather calendar info from multiple calendars but only use one Exchange account.  This one account will be a delegate for the others.  I can get the calendars just fine as long as I know the mailbox of the delegator but I would like to dynamically find the addresses of the delegators.  Is this possible?

Thanks,
Rex

Answer (score 0):

> > I would like to dynamically find the addresses of the delegators

With EWS no you can't, you could do it with the Exchange Management Shell or LDAP by checking the rights on each mailboxes calendar folder to see if the user has rights (but there is no back-linked property that will give you this in the direction you want)

Another workaround is if they have opened the shared calendar in Outlook or OWA then a shortcut will be created in the Mailbox and you can then use that shortcut eg similar to https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/57b313ff-bcef-4457-8cae-0b694ac002ef/how-to-get-shared-calendars-using-ews

Cheers
glen